# Error in XML having inline DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have inline DTD in XML file.When i validate i get error as

> Markup declarations contained in or pointed to by document type
>   declaration must be well-formed.

and

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
 <!DOCTYPE MESSAGE [ 
 <!ELEMENT MESSAGE (USER,SMS+)>
 <!ELEMENT USER EMPTY>
 <!ELEMENT SMS (ADDRESS)>
 <!ELEMENT ADDRESS EMPTY>
 <!ATTLIST MESSAGE  VER CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST USER USERNAME CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST USER PASSWORD CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST SMS TEXT CDATA  #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST SMS ID CDATA  #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST ADDRESS FROM CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST ADDRESS TO CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST ADDRESS SEQ CDATA #REQUIRED>
 ]>
<MESSAGE VER='1.2' ><USER USERNAME='username' PASSWORD='password'/>
<SMS TEXT='message Text' ID='1'>
<ADDRESS FROM='32323233' TO='21212445455' SEQ='11'/>
</SMS><SMS TEXT='Text' ID='2'>
<ADDRESS FROM='text1111111111' TO='9090909090' SEQ='2' />
</SMS> </MESSAGE>
```

Comment: What are you using to validate your XML? As long as you don't have any whitespace (including newlines) before the `<?xml` declaration, it validates fine for me. (Validated with Xerces in oXygen.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurred due to extra spaces between **<** and **?xml** and between  **?** and **>**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the most likely cause of the error message you report is that you have whitespace (a blank) before the XML declaration.  Delete it, so that the XML declaration is the first thing the parser sees in the file.